# Unable to locate package makefile

Tags: software-installation, makefile

Hello everyone I am new in using [Ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GNAL.png) operating system and facing a problem.

I have installed GCC using

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
```

but when I run the following command

```
sudo apt-get install makefile
```

it shows me error "Unable to locate package makefile"

Answer (score 1):

A `makefile` is just a file that is read and processed by the `make` command.

In turn, the `make` command is provided by package `make`. So your command should be

```
sudo apt install make
```

Comment: Or even better, `sudo apt install build-essential`

Comment: I have already done it but when I run the sudo apt-get install mpich2. It again gives the same error Unable to locate package mpich2

Comment: @Bilal you probably want the package named `mpich`. You will need to enable the `universe` repository.